# Usando apenas knockoutJs e jQuery pode substituir o durandalJs?

Tags: knockoutjs, durandal

Bom dia galera, 
Primeiramente, trabalhei num projeto muito grande usando durandal, esse projeto era tecnologia de ponta em web, durandaljs, gulp, entity framework 6 mvc 5 webapi2 e etc

agora surgiu a oportunidade de fazer um parecido só que a minha duvida é:
Posso fazer um projeto sem o durandal e usando apenas o knockout? pq o durandal faz uma especie de modulação com as viewmodels, e dando applybindings "automaticamente" conforme a troca de views. Isso é possivel? Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tudo é possível, nao quer dizer que seja fácil.

O `knockout` apenas faz *data-binding* enquanto o `durandal` tem *routes*, gestao de dependencias, animacoes e gestao de vistas. Por isso se só precisar de *data-binding* pode usar apenas o knockout.

[Fonte](https://johnpapa.net/compare-durandal-to-angular-not-knockout-to-angular/)

Comment: eu conversei com um amigo meu. ele disse que o durandal só configura um monte de coisa pra funcionar tudo kk, entao o que eu quero fazer é praticamente oq o durandal faz. entao eu tenho q estudar msm. Valeu pela resposata